# RMagick replacing transparent color

Tags: ruby, image, imagemagick, png, rmagick

I have a PNG image (PNG 96x96 96x96+0+0 8-bit RGB 2.05KB 0.000u 0:00.000). It's an icon, with a fully transparent background, and a white symbol (its borders are a gradient from transparent to full white). I want to reduce the whole icon opacity to 30% of its initial value. With `convert`, I can do it that way:

```
convert input.png -channel a -evaluate Multiply 0.3 +channel output.png
```

`identify` gives the same output for the resulting image. However, I want to do this from a Ruby script, so I'm using RMagick.

Here's a little test:

```
source = Magick::Image::read(INPUT)[0]
source.write(OUTPUT)
```

This works: I have the exact same image. Still the same output with `identify`. Now, let's change the opacity:

```
source = Magick::Image::read(INPUT)[0]
source.opacity = (Magick::QuantumRange * 0.3).floor
source.write(OUTPUT)
```

The result is wrong: a black background is added before the opacity is reduced. I end up with a 30% opacity black background, and a 30% opacity white icon (which is, for the icon, what I want). Here's the `identify` output: PNG 96x96 96x96+0+0 8-bit RGB 1.06KB 0.000u 0:00.000

I tried to add `PNG32:` in front of my output file name. If the `identify` output changes (PNG 96x96 96x96+0+0 8-bit sRGB 1.29KB 0.000u 0:00.000), the visual result remains the same.

I tried to specify the background color:

```
source = Magick::Image::read(INPUT)[0]
source.opacity = (Magick::QuantumRange * 0.3).floor
source.write(OUTPUT) do
  self.background_color = 'none'
end
```

But I end up with the exact same result.

Any idea of how I can avoid this black background?

Comment: I normally use IM with the command-line and/or Perl or PHP bindings, but not RMagick... however, you may find the scale the opacity is 0..1 rather than 0..65535. I may be wrong - just trying to help.

Comment: Thanks for trying. But I also tried with 0.3: I have a solid black background and a solid white icon. I guess it doesn't allow floats here, and round down to 0 (or to 1, but I didn't really noticed the difference :-)). As my background results in a 30% black, I guess the range is good here.

Comment: Another idea may be to set the background colour to `none` before changing the opacity.

Comment: I just tried, no change.

Comment: `img.quantum_operator(MultiplyQuantumOperator, 0.3, AlphaChannel)` maybe?

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks. Do you have any explanation on why my solution didn't work?

Comment: No, sorry :-) As I said, I am pretty competent with `IM` in `Perl/PHP` and at the command-line but have never used `Ruby` or `RMagick` - I just looked for the `RMagick` that corresponds to your command-line version.

Comment: Well, thanks anyway. Would you mind posting your solution as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like the command that most resembles the one you have had success with at the command-line:

```
img.quantum_operator(MultiplyQuantumOperator, 0.3, AlphaChannel)
```

For future reference, I found it [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/optequiv.html).

Comment: Not sure what this exactly doing since I dont know much about image processing. Mark, could you take a look at this question? Thanks for any and all help! I'm just getting stuck and I'm not sure what is going on.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39576629/how-do-you-use-rmagick-to-apply-a-mask-with-transparent-background